# Как отправить через ajax параметры адресной строки?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Нужно отправить пост запросом параметры `s=123&n=тест&p=10`

Как лучше это сделать?

```js
var parameters = window.location.href; // https://google.com/?s=123&n=тест&p=10

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/index.php',
  processData: false,
  dataType: 'JSON',
  success: function(data){}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Так всё-таки параметры нужны в адресной строке или в теле POST-запроса?

Comment: @andreymal, из адресной строки отправить `post` запросом через `ajax`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получить сам список параметром можно следующим кодом:

```
const params= window
    .location
    .search
    .replace('?','')
    .split('&')
    .reduce(
        function(p,e){
            let a = e.split('=');
            p[ decodeURIComponent(a[0])] = decodeURIComponent(a[1]);
            return p;
        },
        {}
    );

console.log( params['data']);
// выведет в консоль значение  GET-параметра data
```

А отправить почти тем же, что вы указали, но добавить сами данные:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/index.php',
  processData: false,
  dataType: 'JSON',
  data: params,
  success: function(response){...}
});
```

Comment: Все работает, спасибо. Была одна ошибка в параметре `processData: false,` я его удалил и ошибка пропала

Comment: Этот параметр определяет, нужно ли параметры перед отправкой преобразовать в строку. Поэтому он и устанавливается в false, я думал, вам нужно отправить объектом